# merge variables from woocommerce functions

Tags: php, html, function, variables

I want to display the result of 2 functions in the same div. However, I only know how to use the hooks in the following way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'function1', 7 );
  
function function1() {
    // code here
    // echo "<div> text . $var1 . </div>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'function2', 7 );
  
function function2() {
    // code here
    // echo "<div> text . $var2 . </div>";
}
```

Can you help me and tell me how to merge the 2 functions to have a result like this:

```
echo "<div> text .$var1. .var2. </div>";
```

I thought of defining the var1 in the function 2 but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think using **post meta** would be best way to approach this situation. If you are using html values then I also recommend sanitising using `sanitize_text_field` function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'function1', 7 );
  
function function1() {
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "var_1", "var_1_content");
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'function2', 7 );
  
function function2() {
    $var_1 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "var_1", true);
    $var_2 = $var_1 . "var_2_content";

    echo $var_2;
}
```